# Kubernetes secrets encrypted with certificate?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

When Kubernetes creates secrets, do they encrypt the given user name and password with certificate?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: YWRtaW4=
  password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but yes - it's encrypted at rest. The secrets are store at etcd (the database used to store all Kubernetes objects) and you can enable a Key Management System that will be used to encrypt the secrets. You can find all the relevant details on the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/).

Please note that this does not protect the manifests files - which are not encrypted. The secrets are only encrypted on etcd, but when getting them with kubectl or with the API you will get them decrypted.

If you wish to encrypt also the manifest files, there are multiple good solutions to that, like Sealed Secrets, Helm Secrets or Kamus. You can read more about them on my [blog post](https://blog.solutotlv.com/can-kubernetes-keep-a-secret/).

Answer (score 1):

Secrets are stored in etcd which is highly-available key value store fo cluster information data. Data are encrypted at rest. By default, the **identity** provider is used to protect secrets in etcd, which provides no encryption.

EncryptionConfiguration was introduced to encrypt secrets locally, with a locally managed key. 
Encrypting secrets with a locally managed key protects against an etcd compromise, but it fails to protect against a host compromise. 
Since the encryption keys are stored on the host in the EncryptionConfig YAML file, a skilled attacker can access that file and extract the encryption keys. This was a stepping stone in development to the kms provider, introduced in 1.10, and beta since 1.12. Envelope encryption creates dependence on a separate key, not stored in Kubernetes. 
In this case, an attacker would need to compromise etcd, the kubeapi-server, and the third-party KMS provider to retrieve the plaintext values, providing a higher level of security than locally-stored encryption keys.

More information you can find here:
[`secrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), [`encryption`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/).

I hope it helps.